# Jasper report - Aggregate function Sum is missing

Tags: java, jasper-reports, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

[image: Aggregation function in jasper reports]

I want to display the sum of a field in the summary band. I just dropped a field in the summary band, As it shows the attached popup image, but the sum function is missing. How to add it to the report?

Comment: What version of netbeans plugin are you using?, consider to download last version of JasperSoft Studio or last version of iReport....

Comment: @PetterFriberg    thanks,I got it. I tried to sum up the string datatype. I figured it out and corrected.

Comment: Great, consider answering your own question and check it accepted.....